# Reintentar cargar imagen en Glide con 2 URL's

Tags: android, android-glide, glide

Estoy cargando una imagen con Glide, de la siguiente manera.

```
Glide.with(myActivity.this).load(url1).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(avatarImageView);
```

Resulta que aveces me falla, ya que aveces la **url1** no existe, y debo cargar una **url2**. *(url1 y url2 es un String que corresponde a la URL de la imagen)*

Quiero saber como reintentar con la url2 si una url1 falla...

Gracias!

EDITO:
url1 y url2 no son null ni estan vacios. Tienen distintos formatos cuando se crearon y debo intentar con un formato primero y si éste no carga, intentar con el otro formato.

Ejemplo:

```
String url1= "http://www.foto.xd/juan_perez_123456.jpg";
String url2= "http://www.foto.xd/123456.jpg";
```

Comment: edite la pregunta y quite la segunda pregunta. En ningún caso es null ni vacio.

Comment: Gracias @Maguz  es más entendible, lo que necesitas es un callback que determine cuando no existe e intentar descargar el otro url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un callback que determine si fallo la carga de la url, en base a esto cargar otra imagen.

Si se encuentra un error puedes usar [.error()](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-exceptions-debugging-and-error-handling) y definir una imagen de tus recursos.

Pero en este caso deseas cargar en caso de error otra imagen mediante un url, por lo tanto puedes cargar la imagen dentro de `onException()` que es llamado si ocurrió un error al cargar la primera imagen:

```
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(url1)               
           // .error(R.drawable.androide_error)
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    // log exception
                    Log.e("Glide", "Error Cargando imagen!!! ", e);

                    //Procede a cargar otra imagen...
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url2)
                            .into(avatarImageView);

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.i("Glide", "Carga de imagen sin problemas!!!");
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(avatarImageView);
```

Para más información puedes ver la [documentación oficial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-exceptions-debugging-and-error-handling).

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó. Voy a revisar la otra respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el callback de Glide y manejar el error, en caso la primera imagen te de algún error vuelves a cargarla con Glide...

```
Glide.with(myActivity.this).load(url1).
    diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).
    into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
        avatarImageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
        //En el caso que falle url1  
        Glide.with(myActivity.this).
            load(url2).
            diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).
            into(avatarImageView);
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias, pero, no puedo ejecutar el código. me marca error en el into: Class 'Anonymous class derived from SimpleTarget' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onResourceReady(R, GlideAnimation<? super R>)' in 'Target

Comment: @Maguz dependiendo de la version de Glide el callBack puede ser diferente, yo uso "4.0.0-RC1", ve la implementacion del metodo "into()" de glide que usas para que puedas ver que callback (o Target) usar.